# Чтение из нескольких каналов

Tags: rust

Коим образом в потоке читать из нескольких каналов? Это возможно ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В стандартной библиотеке есть макрос [`select!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.select.html), но его можно
   использовать только с ночной сборкой компилятора.
2. На crates.io целая [куча библиотек про каналы](https://crates.io/keywords/channel). Вот две, в которых эта возможность реализована:

   - [chan](https://docs.rs/chan/0.1.21/chan/#example-select-on-multiple-channel-sendsreceives)
   - [crossbeam-channel](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/0.1.2/crossbeam_channel/#selection)

Вообще, стоит попробовать складывать все сообщения в один канал. У стандартных `mpsc` каналов (multi-producer, single-consumer)  может быть сколько угодно входных точек [`Sender`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html). Если нужно принимать сообщения разных типов, то их можно заворачивать в `Enum`.